# How to clean sys.conversation_endpoints

Tags: sql-server-2005, msmq

I have a table, a trigger on the table implemented using service broker. More than Half million records are inserted daily into the table.

The asynchronous SP is used to check sveral condition by using inserted data and update other tables. It was running fine for last 1 month and the SP was get executed withing 2-3 seconds of insertion of record. But now it take more than 90 minute.

At present sys.conversation_endpoints have too much records.

(Note that all the table are truncated daily as I do not need those records day after)

Other database activities are normal (average 60% CPU Utilization).

Now where i need to look??

I can re-create database without any problem but i don't think it is a good way to resolve the problem

Comment: We have more than 19 million records. How do you handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can 'end conversation @handle' or 'end conversation @handle with cleanup'

Answer (score 2):

Script to end all conversations for a particular service:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@far_service NVARCHAR(256) = N'far_service_name';

WHILE EXISTS (
                 SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM   sys.conversation_endpoints
                 WHERE  far_service = @far_service
             )
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'';
    SELECT TOP 1000 @sql = @sql + N'END CONVERSATION ''' + CAST(conversation_handle AS NVARCHAR(50)) + N''' WITH CLEANUP;
'
    FROM   sys.conversation_endpoints
    WHERE  far_service = @far_service;

    --PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;

    --RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, after modifying code from @thesqldev

```
USE [MY_DATABASE_NAME_HERE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mqConversationsClearAll]

AS

-- Note: you can check the queue by running this query
-- SELECT * FROM sys.conversation_endpoints GO


DECLARE @getid CURSOR
        ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@conv_id NVARCHAR(100)
        ,@conv_handle NVARCHAR(100)
        ,@conv_service NVARCHAR(100)
        -- ,@far_service NVARCHAR(256) = N'One_Specific_Service_Target';

-- want to create and execute a chain of statements like this, one per conversation
-- END CONVERSATION 'FE851F37-218C-EA11-B698-4CCC6AD00AE9' WITH CLEANUP;
-- END CONVERSATION 'A4B4F603-208C-EA11-B698-4CCC6AD00AE9' WITH CLEANUP;    

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
                SELECT [conversation_id], [conversation_handle], [far_service]
                FROM   sys.conversation_endpoints
                WHERE NOT([State] = 'CO') 
                -- CO = CONVERSING [State]
                -- alternatively, might like one service name only
                -- WHERE  far_service = @far_service

OPEN @getid

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @conv_id, @conv_handle, @conv_service
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = 'END CONVERSATION ' + char(39) + @conv_handle + char(39) + ' WITH CLEANUP;'
            EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;
            FETCH NEXT
            FROM @getid INTO @conv_id, @conv_handle, @conv_service
        END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Then you can execute the newly created stored procedure "mqConversationsClearAll" whenever you want to clear sys.conversation_endpoints